# Is there a way to select an element AND siblings in css and/or less?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

Often I want to style an element AND its younger siblings. Suppose I want to style the third `span` and all following ones. I know that I can do this:

```
span:nth-child(2) ~ span
{
    width: 125px;
}
```

In English, this says "get the **second** `span` and style all *following* ones". So this effectively does style from the *third* one on.

But I don't like this syntax, because:

- I have to read this carefully every single time, because it's not easy to understand.
- If I change the HTML to use a `div` instead of a `span`, I have to change the corresponding CSS in **two** places.

So, is there any way, possibly using a LESS function or mixin, to do the equivalent of:

```
span:nth-child-or-following(3)
{
    width: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `span:nth-child(n + 3) { ... }`

so there's no tag repetition and you would naturally use the index starting from `3`

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xENGXx)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Not sure how I missed that one.